# Use of count command

Tags: stata

I am using a dataset, which among other variables includes the following:

```
. describe year country co brand

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
year            int     %9.0g                 year (=first dimension of panel)
country         byte    %9.0g      market     market (=second dimension of panel)
co              int     %9.0g                 model code (=third dimension of panel)
brand           byte    %21.0g     brand      brand code
```

After I load the dataset, I generate a new variable and declare my data to be panel:

```
egen yearcountry = group(year country), label
xtset co yearcountry
```

I would like to estimate the market share of each brand in each country.

For example:

```
count if brand=="AlfaRomeo" & country=="Italy"
```

However, i get the following error:

```
type mismatch
r(109);
```

The entire dataset consisting of `11,483` observations can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/bjornerstedt/mergersim/blob/master/mergersim2/cars1.dta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
. count if brand == 1 & country == 4
  111
```

The variables `brand` and `country` are not string but numeric with value labels:

```
. tabulate country

     market |
   (=second |
  dimension |
  of panel) |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
    Belgium |      2,641       23.00       23.00
     France |      2,252       19.61       42.61
    Germany |      2,281       19.86       62.47
      Italy |      2,020       17.59       80.07
         UK |      2,289       19.93      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |     11,483      100.00

. taulate country, nolabel

     market |
   (=second |
  dimension |
  of panel) |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |      2,641       23.00       23.00
          2 |      2,252       19.61       42.61
          3 |      2,281       19.86       62.47
          4 |      2,020       17.59       80.07
          5 |      2,289       19.93      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |     11,483      100.00
```

However, note that what you are calculating here is not the market share, but the number of cars of a particular brand in a certain country. The percentage market share is usually defined as the ratio of unit sales and total market unit sales.

The following code snippet will thus produce what you want:

```
forvalues i = 1 / 47 {
    bysort year (country): egen a_`i' = total(brand == `i')
    bysort year (country):  gen b_`i' = (a_`i' / _N) * 100
}

collapse b_*, by(country year)
```

You can also check that the results add up as follows:

```
egen all = rowtotal(b_*)
```

You could then see the market share for `AlfaRomeo` & `Audi`, for years `1970` & `1976` and for `Belgium` & `France` as follows:

```
format b_* all %4.2f

list year country b_1 b_2 all if inlist(year,1970, 1976) & inlist(country, 1, 2), noobs

  +---------------------------------------+
  | year   country    b_1    b_2      all |
  |---------------------------------------|
  | 1970   Belgium   3.31   7.35   100.00 |
  | 1976   Belgium   5.01   4.13   100.00 |
  | 1970    France   3.31   7.35   100.00 |
  | 1976    France   5.01   4.13   100.00 |
  +---------------------------------------+
```